# Which API/method does Xender use to bypass Wifi Security

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p, wifi

I am amaze to see how Xender bypass all WIFI related security checks and can connect to any other device easily that have Xender running and then transfer files. In Android, conventionally we create a hotspot and other joins that hotspot but Xender seems to have its own way to connect to other devices(basically same as the conventional method). Is it WIFI direct or something else? I also want to do the same. Can anyone please give some light on this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "Xender makes use of your phone’s Wi-Fi hotspot feature for file transfer" -- Their FAQ

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638335/how-can-i-transfer-files-between-android-devices-using-wi-fi-direct

Comment: actually your questions is right but need to change some words xender bypass security while we go with connect with PC option and specifically create hostpot option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a peer-to-peer connectivity. One mobile acts as a `server` and other as a `client`. And, to create the connection we have to connect the "sockets" of the two mobiles which are created dynamically.
As soon as these sockets get connected, we can send data in form of byte stream, which in the case of Wifi-Direct, is extremely fast.

> The Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P) APIs allow applications to connect to
>   nearby devices without needing to connect to a network or hotspot .
>   Wi-Fi P2P allows your application to quickly find and interact with
>   nearby devices, at a range beyond the capabilities of Bluetooth.

In case of Android's implementation of Wifi-Direct, having multiple servers is not possible. See the [Android's reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pGroup.html). It says:

> A p2p group consists of a single group owner and one or more clients.
>   In the case of a group with only two devices, one will be the group
>   owner and the other will be a group client

reference guide for connectivity can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#connect)

Comment: Can we have many clients and one server in peer-to-peer connectivity?

Comment: Yes. For example, look at Chat Systems. There can be many people chatting to each other and one server that handles all the messages sent among them. In case of Android's implementation of wifi-direct, having multiple servers is not possible.

Comment: Can a device be server as well as client at the same time?

Comment: of course. You can register server on one port and, make all clients listen to that port whether they are on same machine or not. While developing a server-to-client application, developers usually test the code by running server and client on same machine.

Comment: Actually i have a code that use DatagramSocket for the same but it requires to create a hotspot manually in the first device and then manually join second device to the first one. I want to bypass this manually process of creating a hotspot and then joining it. Can't i do this programmatically?